# Windows Phone 7 Back Button Handling through Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, cordova

I want to know that how we can perform an event when we hit on win phone 7 back button through javascript..

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady() {
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown() {
//want to redirect a particular page.?? want to handle functioning of back button
}
```

Comment: if it were possible, which im not sure it is, this would be an incredibly annoying feature and would guarantee most users never return to your site/app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>gaurish's Cordova Back Button Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Call onDeviceReady when Cordova is loaded.
    //
    // At this point, the document has loaded but cordova-2.0.0.js has not.
    // When Cordova is loaded and talking with the native device,
    // it will call the event `deviceready`.
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to call Cordova methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }

    // Handle the back button
    //
    function onBackKeyDown() {
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

now, to test this

1. Add some code into `onBackKeyDown()` which you want to run, example

   `function onBackKeyDown() {
       currentId = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
       if(currentId == "#swipediv"){
       $.mobile.changePage("#home", "slide", false, true);
       }
       else{
       history.go(-1);
       }
   }`
2. Loadup `cordova-2.0.0.js`
3. checkout [WP7 PhoneGap Backbutton Support Re-visited](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/01/wp7-phonegap-backbutton-support-re-visited/)
4. read the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton)

If this still doesn't work, file a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB).